# SQL Server trigger to insert data from multiple table to another if a condition is met

Tags: sql-server, database, join, triggers

I want to write a SQL Server trigger.

I have 4 tables:

1. PRD.dbo.DefectDetail
2. PRD.dbo.Quality
3. PRD.dbo.Result
4. RPT.SPC.Report (QualityDataID, LineID, LineName, ProgramName, ReportDate, ReportHour, PartNo, Location, DefectCode, ResultGUID, Code, CavityIndex)

I want to insert data from query of first 3 table to table 4 if a certain condition is met:

```
SELECT 
    dd.QualityDataID, qd.LineID, qd.LineName, qd.ProgramName, 
    qd.ReportDate, qd.ReportHour, dd.PartNo, dd.Location, 
    dd.DefectCode, dd.ResultGUID, ar.Code, dd.PCBCavityIndex
FROM
    PRD.dbo.DefectDetail dd WITH(NOLOCK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    PRD.dbo.Quality qd WITH(NOLOCK) ON qd.QualityID = dd.QualityDataID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    PRD.dbo.Result ar WITH(NOLOCK) ON dd.ResultGUID = ar.ResultGUID
WHERE 
    dd.QualityType = 1 
    AND dd.CreatedDate > ''
```

Is it possible to insert data into `RPT.SPC.Report` once there is data entry of this query?

How to handle `dd.createddate` (trigger what have inserted in first 3 table)? Do I need to create another table to store the last inserted record by storing `createddate`, so that can get what data should I insert by `createddate`. Else, do the trigger function will replace `dd.createddate`?

Hope someone can enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: What do you mean by `once there is data entry of this query`? Do you understand how triggers work?

Comment: Why do you need to insert anything? Just create a view with the query your wrote

Comment: This sounds like [an XY Problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjF1tbdhsiCAxVOUqQEHckfAMAQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AOvVaw1RW8UpIl7QYxoW-PU7zAk9&opi=89978449). What are ou trying to achieve here ?